# Laravel: Use Email and Name in Mail::to

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have a contact form where someone provides his name and email. I want to send him an email now with Laravel.

I found in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#sending-mail)

> To send a message, use the to method on the Mail facade. The to method
>   accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users.

and in fact

> \Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\Hello);

works. But is it also possible to provide the **name** for the email receipt?

I wanted to look that up in the Laravel API for the [Mail Facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Mail.html) but to my surprise the facade has no **to** function?

So how can I find out what the **to** function really does and if I can pass a name parameter as well?

Comment: are you looking for this public function to($address, $name = null, $override = false)

Comment: The `Mail` facade gets a `Mailer` instance: you can find the docs here. https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html

Comment: @Bugfixer YES! Thanks! Where can I find this line in the code? I could not find this function in the `Mailer` class?

Comment: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php

Comment: @Bugfixer thank you. Since the method is in the `message`class, I guess that I cannot use `Mail::to` but I need to pass the email and name to the `Mailable` class and there I can specify `to` on the message?

Comment: use third param $callback of public function send() to give name with recipient email.

Comment: @Bugfixer since I pass an instance of `MailableContract`  to the `public function send()` the `$callback` parameter is ignored. I guess its the easiest way to just pass `$request` to my `MailableContract` instance then?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In laravel 5.6, answer to your question is: use associative array for every recpient with 'email' and 'name' keys, should work with $to, $cc, $bcc

```
$to = [
    [
        'email' => $email, 
        'name' => $name,
    ]
];
\Mail::to($to)->send(new \App\Mail\Hello);
```

Comment: Be careful to pass array of arrays (not just one array with `email` and `name`).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Mail::send() function that inject a `Message` class in the callable. The `Message` class has a function `to($email, $name)` with the signature you're searching, i.e.:

```
Mail::send($view, $data, function($message) use ($email, $name) {
    $m->to($email,  $name);
    $m->from('youremail@example.com', 'Your Name'); 
    $m->subject('Hi there');
})
```

The $view could be a string (an actual view) or an array like these:

```
['text'=> 'body here']
['html'=> 'body here']
['raw'=> 'body here']
```

The $data argument will be passed to the $view.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel < 5.6 one can use this:

```
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->email = $email;
$object->name  = $user->getName();

\Mail::to($object)->queue($mailclass);
```

see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#sending-mail)

Comment: You can also pass in an instance of `\App\Models\User` or event an array of it.

Comment: @Frank its true, but since its just a contact form, I do not have a user model, just name and email.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this solution as more readable (no need to use arrays and static string keys).

```
\Mail::send((new \App\Mail\Hello)
    ->to('example@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mailable class in Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

```
php artisan make:mail YouMail
```

These classes are stored in the app/Mail directory.

In config/mail.php you can configue email settings:

```
'from' => ['address' => 'example@example.com', 'name' => 'App Name'],
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking how to change the `to` setting locally and not how to change `from` globally

Answer (score 0):

for Laravel 8 is like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->email = 'example@example.com';
Mail::to($user)->send(new YourMail);
```

YourMail is Mailable class created by `php artisan make:mail YourMail`

Comment: Thats default behaviour since Laravel 5 at least