# I want to send an email in laravel using the email used by the client account

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail

I'm new to Laravel and I'm doing this for a thesis project. What I was trying to do is I want to send an email to the client that sent a payment after the admin has confirmed the payment. what I tried is attaching an $email to the MailController so that a predefined email will be used when sending. I used another controller that forwards the email to my MailController

```
public function paymentAccept($Pymnt_ID)
{
    $email = Users::select('users.User_email')
        ->join('payment', 'users.User_ID', '=', 'payment.User_ID')
        ->where('payment.Pymnt_ID', $Pymnt_ID)
        ->get();

    //find payment id then update
    $accept = Payment::find($Pymnt_ID);
    $accept->Pymnt_Status = 'Received';
    $accept->save();

    if ($accept) {
        return redirect('admin/sendEmail')->with($email);
    } else {
        return back()->with('fail', 'Something went wrong, try again later');
    }
}
```

then this is my MailController.

```
public function sendMail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
    $data = [

        'subject' => 'Payment Confirmation',
        'body' => 'Your payment has been confirmed. Your job order will now proceed to the designing process.',

    ];
    Mail::to($email)->send(new Test($data));
    return view('admin.sendEmail');
}
```

I also use this

```
<?php

  namespace App\Mail;

  use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
  use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
  use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

  class Test extends Mailable
 {
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

private $data = [];

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('abcg@example.com', 'ABC Printing')
    ->subject($this->data['subject'])
    ->markdown('admin.Test')->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

}

Comment: So what problem are you having? You might actually want to use [events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/events) or [notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications) instead of redirecting, or even add the mailer directly in your paymentAccept with a [Laravel Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail)

Comment: what I'm getting is Illegal offset  type, based on my understanding it's problem when accepting arrays of array, I found this earlier as a reference but I cannot understand what I should do instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47905130/laravel-use-email-and-name-in-mailto

Comment: Please edit te question and share the log trace as well.

Comment: Please provide the full and exact error message that you're getting

Comment: Not much we can do without the actual error ...